# Ember Powerselect data format

Tags: ember.js

I am looking the documentation of the format of the how it needs to be. But I am wondering how I could add the id of the options.

```
groupedNumbers: [
    { groupName: 'Smalls', options: ['one', 'two', 'three'] },
    { groupName: 'Mediums', options: ['four', 'five', 'six'] },
    { groupName: 'Bigs', options: [
        { groupName: 'Fairly big', options: ['seven', 'eight', 'nine'] },
        { groupName: 'Really big', options: [ 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve' ] },
        'thirteen'
      ]
    },
    'one hundred',
    'one thousand'
  ]
```

Here is what I am looking to do

```
groupedNumbers: [
    { groupName: 'Smalls', options: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'one'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'two'
    }]
  ]
```

Here is where I am calling the componet

```
<label for="menu-group-list">Service Category</label>
{{#power-select
  options=groupedCategories
  searchEnabled=true
  selected=selectedSubCategoryName
  selectedItemComponent="selected-service"
  onchange=(action "serviceSubCategoryChanged")
  as |category| }}
    {{category}}
{{/power-select}}
```

I thought I could override the `optionsComponent` but that did not work. Thoughts?

Comment: Is that code in your controller or in a component?

Comment: Well its not code, its what the expected response is

Answer (score 0):

1. `options=groupedCategories` here you need to provide `options=groupedNumbers`
2. Instead of `{{category}}` you need to say `{{category.name}}`